# How to override vuex store data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a reusable vue.js contact form component that could be used for creating new contacts or updating contacts. I have a store that keeps track of which contact a user wants to edit called `contactToEdit` and I assign it to a computed variable called `contact`. However, I also have a data model called `contact`, which gets used when the user wants to add a contact. Therefore, when I am using the component to add a contact, is there a way I can override the computed contact variable (since it will be undefined at this point)? Or can I conditionally tell the component to use the `contact` from the vuex store vs. the default contact modal? Here is my vue component for reference:

```
<template>
    <form class="padded-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" v-model="contact.first_name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" v-model="contact.last_name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" v-model="contact.contact_email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone #</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" v-model="contact.contact_phone_number">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Notes</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="" rows="4" v-model="contact.contact_notes"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><button class="btn btn-primary btn" v-if="adding" @click="addContact(contact)">Submit</button></div>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"><button class="btn btn-primary btn" v-if="editing" @click="saveContact(contact)">Save</button></div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      contact: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        contact_email: '',
        contact_phone_number: '',
        contact_notes: ''
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      contact: 'contactToUpdate',
      editing: 'editingContact',
      adding: 'addingContact',
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already have `addContact(contact)` method defined in your template. Inside this method you can commit your Vuex mutation which overwrites the 'contact' Vuex state property, so when you click a button the state is mutated and your `contact` getter updates. Or maybe I misunderstood your question?